# How to force iPad Safari not to scale down my web page in portrait mode?

Tags: html, ipad, safari, portrait

I am publishing a free book online in HTML5 format and i said it would be great if i could optimize it for the iPad even though i don't have one.

So i started working on the design and that idea was in my head all the time. I made the design just to fit the iPad screen in portrait mode, then i tried to test it and i discovered that Safari is scaling down the whole website to fit pages into its screen which screwed my design and pissed me off (my bad i didn't do too much research) and Apple won't let me have an iPad emulator cause i don't have a Mac!!

**Anyway.. is there is any way i could force Safari to ignore that behavior and let my readers enjoy my 1:1 scale desgin? something like CSS media query or some javascript?**

http://mmahgoub.com/thebook/foreword.html

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
```

in your head.

Comment: This will have the (sometimes unfortunate) side-effect of causing iPhones to be unable to zoom the content larger in order to read it.

Comment: Works great for full-screen maps!

Comment: If zoom gets disabled, it's no side-effect. `"user-scalable = no"` prevents this. If you'd like zooming to remain intact, just omit that part.

Comment: <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width"> works for me... (no scale at initial load)

Answer (score -1):

Here is an online iPad simulator that you you can use. It's not Xcode, but it is useful nonetheless.

http://ipadpeek.com/

Comment: That "iPad simulator website" is nothing more than an iFrame with an skin, it does no specific iPad CSS and renders completely different. Just so you know, it might work great on there, but completely different on the iPad itself.